# Get slidingpanellayout events

Tags: java, android, android-studio, slidingpanelayout

I'm using sliding panels with my android app, but i need to get an event when the panel is up, is there a way listen to when it happens?

im using a sothree Sliding panel library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are talking about [umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel). After briefly looking at the documentation/code you should be able to set a [PanelSlideListener](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/blob/81e3d5a3ed811cff86efa0680e9e49b2efa91a2b/library/src/com/sothree/slidinguppanel/SlidingUpPanelLayout.java#L521-L528) to your `SlidingUpPanelLayout`. They also provide a [SimplePanelSlideListener](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/blob/81e3d5a3ed811cff86efa0680e9e49b2efa91a2b/library/src/com/sothree/slidinguppanel/SlidingUpPanelLayout.java#L266-L289) which inserts no-ops for any functions you choose not to implement, which is probably what you will want to use.

For example inside of your Activity's `onCreate` you could do something like:

```
SlidingUpPanelLayout slidingPanel = (SlidingUpPanelLayout)findViewById(R.id.your_sliding_layout);
slidingPanel.setPanelSlideListener(new SimplePanelSlideListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPanelExpanded(View panel) {
        // Insert your code here
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! that was exactly what i was looking for